# Testing with meteor and jasmine: Iron Router Routing does not work as expected

Tags: meteor, jasmine, iron-router

I am trying to write tests for a meteor app with the velocity/jasmine framework.

My boss wants a UI testing (End-To-End) so I need to write tests for the User Interface.

I now have the problem how I should test the normal Navigation through the app. My Idea to test for example the user registration procedure was something like this:

```
describe 'Login and Usermanagement System', ->
    it 'should say the user is logged out when no user is logged in', ->
        # This test Works
        expect(Meteor.user()).toBeFalsy()

    it 'should show a welcome screen if the user is logged out', ->
        currentUrl = Router.current().location.get().href;
        routeName = Router.current().route.getName();

        # This test Works as the startpage in our app (When you hit /) is always system.welcome as long as you are not logged in.
        expect(routeName).toBe("system.welcome")

    it 'should show a register screen if the user is logged out and clicked on register', (done) ->
        Router.go("/register")
        routeName = Router.current().route.getName()

        # This test does not work as the Router.go seems to be async.
        expect(routeName).toBe("system.register")
```

my problem is the third test. I need some kind of callback when a route has loaded to do the next stuff. Of yourse I could wait for 2 seconds or so, but this would slow down my tests unnecesarily.

Is there such a thing as `Router.go(route, options, callback)` or how can I get such a behaviour?

Technology we are using: MeteorJS with Iron Router for Routing, Velocity Test Framework with Jasmine for Testing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the helper described here in the documentation [Integration Tests With Iron Router](https://velocity.readme.io/docs/jasmine-integration-tests-with-iron-router)

Which states:
Save this helper to `tests/jasmine/client/integration/lib/wait_for_router_helper.js` or `tests/jasmine/client/unit/_wait_for_router_helper.js` depending on the mode you want to use:

```
(function (Meteor, Tracker, Router) {
  var isRouterReady = false;
  var callbacks = [];

  window.waitForRouter = function (callback) {
    if (isRouterReady) {
      callback();
    } else {
      callbacks.push(callback);
    }
  };

  Router.onAfterAction(function () {
    if (!isRouterReady && this.ready()) {
      Tracker.afterFlush(function () {
        isRouterReady = true;
        callbacks.forEach(function (callback) {
          callback();
        });
        callbacks = []
      })
    }
  });

  Router.onRerun(function () {
    isRouterReady = false;
    this.next();
  });

  Router.onStop(function () {
    isRouterReady = false;
    if (this.next) {
      this.next();
    }
  });
})(Meteor, Tracker, Router);
```

Then you use it in your tests like this:

```
describe('My Spec', function () {
  beforeEach(function (done) {
    Router.go('/myPage');
    Tracker.afterFlush(done);
  });

  beforeEach(waitForRouter);

  it('should do something', function () {
    // Your test
  });
});
```

Comment: How would it be possible to wait for Router inside of a "it" block? I need to navigate through multiple routes to test some stuff (e.g. go to login page, create user, change password and then check if password is changed)

Comment: Not sure on that one either and definitely on my list to figure out and I haven't been able to do so yet. You might have to create another wrapped function to call.